# Node.js, can't install enmap-level on MacOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

so I am making a Discord Application in which I need a specific package. For some reason, I cannot install this package (using npm), and I think part of the problem is that I am on MacOS and I need windows-build-tools to be able to install the package. Because I am on MacOS I can't install the windows-build-tools. So I guess I am looking for a way either around the windows-build-tools or a substitute for it.
I would appreciate any help I could get.

```
error: hastebin.com/kesigowali.sql
debug log: hastebin.com/kovifafubu.pl
```

Comment: What's the specific command you're entering (`npm install enmap-level`?) and what's the error that you get?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.
error: https://hastebin.com/kesigowali.sql
debug log: https://hastebin.com/kovifafubu.pl

Comment: I wish you the best of luck. I've been in the node-gyp boat a few times, and the solution always seems slightly different: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809